# Why do I get a non-integral value error when using Cplex in python?

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, cplex

I have hit a wall for many months now trying to use Cplex for a large linear program. I am using the populatingbynonzero method to create the coefficient matrix but when invoking linear_constraints.set_coefficients, the same error is always raised:

TypeError: non-integral value in input sequence (0)

I have been googling this for ages and I don't even find a hit for the text "non-integral value in input sequence". Has anybody encountered this error?

The function where this error is raised is the following:

```
    def populatebynonzero(self,prob,my_rhs,my_sense,c,my_lb,my_ub,rows,cols,vals):
        prob.objective.set_sense(prob.objective.sense.maximize)
        prob.linear_constraints.add(rhs = my_rhs, senses = my_sense)
        prob.variables.add(obj = c, lb = my_lb, ub = my_ub)
        prob.linear_constraints.set_coefficients(zip(rows, cols, vals))
```

The error is raised when executing the last line of the code above. zip(rows, cols, vals) is a list of three-element tuples. It is supposed to contain the matrix of coefficients in a sparse format. Hence, the first two elements of each tuple should be integer and the last one is float (actual value of the coefficient in the position determined by the first two integers).  I have checked a million times this and I can find nothing close to a non-integral problem in the values that are passed in zip(rows, cols,vals).

Comment: Show all your code minimized so it easier for us to figure out something, and maybe check if one of the values comes as None?

Comment: I have already checked that no element in the tuples is None

Comment: ... I forgot to say thanks. Thanks, RifloSnake! 

Answer (score 0):

In the example lpex1.py you can see

```
def populatebynonzero(prob):
    prob.objective.set_sense(prob.objective.sense.maximize)

    prob.linear_constraints.add(rhs=my_rhs, senses=my_sense,
                                names=my_rownames)
    prob.variables.add(obj=my_obj, ub=my_ub, names=my_colnames)

    rows = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
    cols = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
    vals = [-1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -3.0, 1.0]

    prob.linear_constraints.set_coefficients(zip(rows, cols, vals))
    # can also change one coefficient at a time
    # prob.linear_constraints.set_coefficients(1,1,-3.0)
    # or pass in a list of triples
    # prob.linear_constraints.set_coefficients([(0,1,1.0), (1,1,-3.0)])
```

The rows and cols have to be integer.

At https://medium.com/ibm-data-ai/optimization-simply-do-more-with-less-zoo-buses-and-kids-part2-python-java-c-cc04558e49b5 you can see the same example with the cplex matrix api but also the easier to use docplex. I encourage you to use that one if possible.

Comment: Thanks, Alex! I am completely aware that the rows and cols need to be integer. I specifically stated that in the formulation of my question. Believe me, I have been hitting the wall for months (every time I gather the energy to try again) and nothing obvious explains the error it is raised. I guess I could try docplex. I just have a very simple, although very large, linear program with only continuous decision variables. I just need to feed the cplex with c (the objective coefficients), A (the constraint coefficients) and b (the vector of rhs coefficients). What is the best example for this?

Comment: Hi again, Alex, I have been looking at docplex and there does not seem to be a way to enter the constraints in an efficient manner. All examples I checked seem to use loops (even nested loops!!), itemisations or adding the constraints one by one!! If one needs to repeatedly solve a large linear program, this method of setting the constraints is incredibly inefficient and not time affordable. Is this really the only way to set the constraints? Nothing similar to populatebynonzero, for example?

Comment: I agree with Alex that it is really worth looking again at the more algebraic ways of building your models. The benefits of that approach in terms of simplicity and making the structure of your problem apparent usually outweigh any percieved overheads. In practice the time taken to build a problem are usually miniscule compared to the solving time. The complexity of the code to create your matrix is also significant, and for non-trivial problems will usually include nested loops etc anyway. Thinking about your problem only as a matrix structure can lose so much insight.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around this error! The values of rows, cols and vals were obtained previously with the function:

```
def rows_cols_vals_efficient(self,a):
    rows,cols = np.nonzero(a)
    vals = np.ndarray.flatten(a)
    index_vals = np.nonzero(vals)[0]
    vals = vals[index_vals]
    return rows,cols,vals,len(vals)
```

Apparently, even though the elements of rows and cols were clearly integer, it did not like that they were coming from a numpy array (even though it was transformed into a list later!). I had to turn each element of the array into an integer (again?!) and the whole thing into a list. This was easily done by inserting two lines of code at the end of the function above. Like this:

```
def rows_cols_vals_efficient(self,a):
    rows,cols = np.nonzero(a)
    vals = np.ndarray.flatten(a)
    index_vals = np.nonzero(vals)[0]
    vals = vals[index_vals]
    rows = list(map(lambda x: int(x),rows))
    cols = list(map(lambda x: int(x),cols))
    return rows,cols,vals,len(vals)
```

Thanks for the answers anyway! I cannot believe I have finally solved this! (even if computing time is increased a bit because of those two lines)

Answer (score 0):

Numpy integers differ from "simple" Python ints or floats, though they can be converted easily. The CPLEX Python API only accepts plain Python numbers (int or floats), so will complain hen passed Numpy numbers.
DOcplex, on the contrary, is numpy-friendly, as it manages all conversions
automatically.
However, I understand you built your problem from a matrix, so this will not help. Maybe you can consider using DOcplex in the future if you choose to build a model from expressions.